# how to change realgud:pdb pdb command

Tags: python, realgud

emacs' **GUD** (GrandUnifiedDebugger) provides way to change get **pdb** command name by using.

```
 (setq gud-pdb-command-name "python -m pdb")
```

is there the way to do same with **realgud**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is such a way:

```
(customize-variable 'realgud:pdb-command-name)
```

Comment: thanks I added `(setq realgud:pdb-command-name "python -m pdb")` to my init file.